# Global Exception handler in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In angularjs is it possible to add global exception handler at one place? So even if you miss to add exception handler for any code user will get a proper message. E.g Something went wrong.

Comment: wat type of exception are you talking about.  ?

Comment: I created a services that handles error msgs if that is what you mean

Comment: @SajanChandran common way to handle all the javascript exception

Comment: @jax can you provide as a answer

Comment: there is no one common way to handle all javascript exceptions.

Comment: ya it can be made possible just create a service and  inject in all the controller. if any error occurs just pass alert msz in that service method which will show an alert or customize alert for any error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
angular.module("app")
.factory("$exceptionHandler",  function() {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            //exception handling here
        };
    });
```

From [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)

Comment: Hey Costanza, explain your answers please!

Comment: I think it's pretty self-explanatory.  The function body is the override for exception handling.

Comment: [This is in the official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler), so either you are doing it wrong or you have a bug and you should file a bug report rather than downvoting my answer.

Comment: @R. Salisbury, Dont know why someone downvote you, so +1 for your answer, and indeed... Self Explanatory...

Comment: you've got an orphaned close bracket in the last line: ]

Comment: @R.Salisbury - using this exception method, does anyone know if its possible to also capture (if it exists) the HTML element and/or data that caused the function to error out? As an example, I have a controller used on several template pages, thus if a button `id=button1` on pageA and button `id=button2' on PageB are both calling the same function, I need know which buttonID was clicked and what, if any, data was passed to the $scope function.